# When try to make a new migration table with posts it shows following error

Tags: migration

$ php artisan migrate

Error

Class "CreatePostsTable" not found

at E:\Xampp\htdocs\Udemy\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator.php:453
449▕     public function resolve($file)
450▕     {
451▕         $class = Str::studly(implode('*', array_slice(explode('*', $file), 4)));
452▕
➜ 453▕         return new $class;
454▕     }
455▕
456▕     /**
457▕      * Get all of the migration files in a given path.

1   E:\Xampp\htdocs\Udemy\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator.php:189
Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator::resolve("2020_12_29_055715_create_posts_table")

2   E:\Xampp\htdocs\Udemy\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator.php:165
Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator::runUp("E:\Xampp\htdocs\Udemy\database\migrations/2020_12_29_055715_create_posts_table.php")